# Long exact sequences of Abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I want examples of long exact sequences of Abelian groups, as below, with no morphism being monic.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A@>a>>B\\ 
@AdAA @VVbV\\
D @<<c< C
\end{CD}

I've become interested in the subject but it turns out that I can't construct these sequences. Need help.

If one of the groups is $0$ the sequence is short exact and I want to examine a sort of generalization of that.
\begin{CD}
A@>a>>B\\ 
@AdAA @VVbV\\
0 @<<c< C
\end{CD}

Comment: Are we supposed to read this as an "infinite loop" of morphisms?  Or are these graded groups?  Or what?

Comment: @Randall - As an infinite sequence, repeated in a loop.

Comment: Why is the infinite loopness relevant?  To me that does not generalize a short exact sequence.

Comment: @Randall - But you do know an example?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Let $A=B=C=D= \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and let the maps delete alternating coordinates.  Play around with it until it works. I'm just trying to figure out if it's relevant.

Comment: @Randall - That was a simple example, thank you!

Comment: Note $G \times G \to G\times G$ given by $(a,b) \mapsto (0, a)$ yields an exact "loop" of any length.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez damn, that is a clever answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - I guess you mean direct sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I mean is the following. If you have an exact sequence $$\cdots X_{i-1}\to X_i\to X_{i+1}\to\cdots$$ define for each $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ the module $S_i$ as the direct sum of all the $X_j$ with $j\equiv i\mod 4$, and maps $S_i\to S_{i+1}$, with the indices taken modulo $4$, in the obvious way to get a diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S_0@>>>S_1\\ 
@AAA @VVV\\
S_3 @<<< S_2
\end{CD}

Answer (score 0):

A great comment of MarianoSuárez-Álvarez.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A@>a>>B\\ 
@AdAA @VVbV\\
0 @<<c< C
\end{CD}
$$\oplus$$
\begin{CD}
0@>d'>>A'\\ 
@Ac'AA @VVa'V\\
C' @<<b'< B'
\end{CD}
$$=$$
\begin{CD}
A\oplus 0@>(a,d')>>B\oplus A'\\ 
@A(d,c')AA @VV(b,a')V\\
0\oplus C' @<<(c,b')< C\oplus B'
\end{CD}

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - No but it is very similar and there are a lot of theories about short sequences, if I would need them to create new sequences. Long sequences are more exotic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - Short sequences are more easy to construct.